# Transform a number in symbols in a MySql SELECT

Tags: mysql, select

I want to know if is possible to transform a numeric return (INT column) in a sequence of symbols direct in a MySQL SELECT.

My table is like below:

```
| ID        | category |
|-----------|----------|
| product_1 | 5        |
| product_2 | 4        |
| product_3 | 3        |
```

I want a SQL SELECT like `SELECT ID, some_mysql_fancy_func(category,'*') AS symbol_category FROM MyTable` that could returns the following:

```
| ID        | symbol_category |
|-----------|-----------------|
| product_1 | *****           |
| product_2 | ****            |
| product_3 | ***             |
```

Is it possible?

I can do it programmatically, but this is not my intention, I want some built-in (or even custom) function that can achieve this result direct in the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT ID,
       REPEAT('*', IFNULL(category, 0)) AS SymbolCategory
    FROM ...
```

This assumes you want `NULL` to be equivalent to 0.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe use `LPAD` or `RPAD`?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tt (category INT UNSIGNED);
INSERT INTO tt(category)
VALUES
(5);

select lpad('*',category,'*')
from tt;
```

Granted, this wouldn't work for 0, or you'd have to replace single * with a NULL value. But an idea at least.